# Why does compactMap return a nil result?

Tags: swift, swift4.1

Consider this code snippet:

```
var a: String? = "abc"
var b: String?

let result = [a, b].compactMap { $0 }
```

After executing it, `result` will be

```
["abc"]
```

which is the expected result. The element of result (`ElementOfResult`) here is `String`.

```
print(type(of: result))
Array<String>
```

Now to the interesting part. After changing the snippet to

```
var a: String? = "abc"
var b: Int?

let result = [a, b].compactMap { $0 }
```

and executing it, `result` will be

```
[Optional("abc"), nil]
```

The element of result (`ElementOfResult`) here is `Any` which makes sense, because `Any` is the common denominator of `String` and `Int`.

```
print(type(of: result))
Array<Any>
```

Why was a `nil` result returned by `compactMap` which contradicts its definition?

From Apple's `compactMap` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap)

> ### compactMap(_:)
>
> Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.
>
> ### Declaration
>
> func compactMap(_ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]

Comment: What is more puzzling is why the type of `result` is `[Any]`. I would have expected it to be `[Any?]`

Comment: @user1046037 `compactMap` is there to remove nil. What sense does it make to return [Any?] if `compactMap` already made sure none of them is nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `[a, b]` is considered a `[Any]`. When the element types in an array literal are entirely unrelated (`Int?` and `String?`), the array type is inferred to be `[Any]`.

In the closure passed to `compactMap`, you returned `$0`, which is of type `Any`. This means that `$0` can never be `nil`. All the optionals inside the array are all wrapped in an `Any` the moment you put them in the array. Because you never return a `nil` in the closure, all the elements stay in the result array.

The compiler can warn you about wrapping optionals in non-optional `Any`s:

```
var a: String? = "abc"

let any: Any = a // warning!
```

But unfortunately it doesn't warn you when you create arrays.

Anyway, you can get the expected behaviour by specifying that you want a `[Any?]`:

```
let result = ([a, b] as [Any?]).compactMap { $0 }
```

So you kind of unwrap them from `Any`.

Or:

```
let result = [a as Any?, b as Any?].compactMap { $0 }
```

> Why can an optional type be wrapped inside an `Any`?

According to the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342) (In the Type Casting for `Any` and `AnyObject` section):

> `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

Thus, `Optional<T>` undoubtedly can be represented by `Any`.

Comment: Based on the original example, wondering how result can be of the type `[Any]` and still hold a `nil`

Comment: @user1046037 Because anything is `Any`. `Any` can hold every type.

Comment: The following code throws a compilation error, `let x : Any = nil`

Comment: @user1046037 `nil` isn‘t inside the resulting array, but an optional which is nil which only prints `nil`.

Comment: My bad, Any can be nil, `var y : Int? = nil; let x : Any = y as Any`

Answer (score 1):

You create an Any-array and compactMap over its elements gives `compactMap` only Any-elements, no `Optional<Any>` which it could think about being nil or not, so all emenents stay.